# How to set the rvalue of an object item equal to a variable and not just a value?

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference

The following prints 3 as expected.

```
let bar = 3
let obj = { foo: bar }
console.log(obj.foo);
```

However if I change the value of bar, the value of obj.foo doesn't change. Also if I change the value of obj.foo, the value of bar doesn't change.

This tells me that when the object is created, it didn't really use bar as an rvalue, it used its value as the value. How do I define obj differently so that the two values always match?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not too sure about this one, but I would suggest making use of
`get` and `set` functions inside the object.

Comment: JS does not have pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a getter and a setter

```js
let bar = 3;
let obj = { 
    get foo() { return bar },
    set foo(newValue) { bar = newValue }
};
console.log(obj.foo); // will show current value of 'bar'
obj.foo = 7 // will change 'bar' to 7
```

See MDN for more info on [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of replying this but I'm not sure if the guy who asked this wanted to be able to do `obj.bar = 5` or something like that to set `bar`

Comment: ah they actually did ask that, let me update